# Add default values for swashbuckle/swagger on a Web API controller action

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

In a C# Web Api controller, how do I decorate an action's parameter, so that a default value for that parameter shows up in swagger?

Comment: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/284

Comment: Thanks @Rebecca, I've seen something similar to this but it was missing the [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)] , so it wouldn't work for more than one parameter. The only problem with this example is that it populates the parameter field in swagger rather than just providing a sample input to the right. I've seen this done in .Net before, I never thought it would be so hard to implement. :(

Comment: If you could use an object as a parameter, then the property inside could use [DefaultValue("Whatever")] on that property. I.e. IActionResult Post(MyRequest request). Where class MyRequest { [DefaultValue("Whatever")]public string Message { get; set; } }

Comment: This Default value will be there for every request. Correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below, I am considering input object for Action method as Product as you have not mentioned anything explicitly in your question.

1. You can use `///<example>value </example>` tag in your Request Field.

   public class Product
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }

   ```
   ///<summary>
   ///</summary>
   ///<example>example value</example>
   public string Description { get; set; }
   ```

   }
  2.

For Default value of parameters in Action Methods, you can directly use as below:

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Action Method Summary
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="Description">example value</param>
```

Comment: Tried option 2 with web api core 3, but it doesn't work

Comment: Could you please share your code? will try to see what's wrong.